# Are rolling updates possible with managed VMs?

Tags: google-app-engine, managed-vm

We began using managed VMs over the sandboxed environment and experienced that even though multiple instances of the application were running, the platform didn't roll them out in a `rolling` fashion so we hit 503s on a regular base while deploying.

Are we missing something in terms of health checks or the like?

Answer (score 0):

Managed VMs (Flex environment) does not yet support full rolling updates. The recommended way would be to always deploy into a new incremental version, ensure that new version is serving fine and then start ramping up production traffic to it using traffic splitting feature.